# Are there any similar sdn controllers to POX controller

Tags: controller, sdn, mininet, openflow, pox

I am newbie to SDN and i have little experience with POX controller but i want to do the same work(same topology , same openflow rules) done using POX controller by using another controller. Can anybody give me any suggestions for pox like controllers to do my work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Opendaylight: Based on Java. However,when I tried it in one of my GNS3 projects, it was too cumbersome and I could not design my own custom code swiftly
2. RYU controller: It is based on python programming language. I am currently using it and have written several python scripts for capturing Netflow traffic. I find it light to use too.

Comment: thanks for the answer i am already start doing it with floodlight controller but i am having issue with running a custom topology as you mentioned in Opendaylight controller. Cannot run my custom topology  ☹️